# Is there a way to unit test data under moor sqlite db which is in application directory?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, unit-testing, dart, flutter-moor

Im trying to perform unit testing on moor sqlite db but unable to do it because it tries to fetch the db from path provider(file path) which fails in unit testing file. Mock framework is not working in this case. Is there any workaround to get path containing db?

Comment: Did you take a look at this? https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/testing/#writing-tests

Comment: yes. But that doesn't involve testing with already stored data

Comment: I think you'll have to copy your db locally and use the path to fetch it and run your tests on the copy. If that doesn't work maybe add your code from both the app and the test to your question to make it more clear what you're dealing with.

Comment: Thats the main issue. I'm not able to fetch DB locally by path using path provider.